# Two containers resizing unexpectedly in flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a following situation:

```
<div display:flex>
   <div1 width:50%/>
   <div2 width:50%/>
</div>
```

These two divs inside (div1 and div2) have `width: 50%` (each of them). The `div2` initially is an empty `div`, **however** its a container for `img` inside.

My problem: when user drops file and a preview is appearing in `img`, these containers (`div1` and `div2`) are resizing (they change their widths, so it's not 50% each of them anymore).

My question: How to force these two containers `div1` and `div2` to NOT RESIZE in every case? 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you think your inline CSS is correct ? the style attribute is missing.

Comment: @rach8garg its just a quick preview how the coode looks

Comment: You should add your actual code, or better yet make a demo so others can see what the problem is

Comment: Use `flex-basis: 50%; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;` on the inner divs to prevent the resizing.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below snippet helps.

```css
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex-child{
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <div class="flex-child">Content 1</div>
   <div class="flex-child">Content 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with your snippet is, if you add a really large image, the children will not be 50% even anymore:)

Comment: In that case use the `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` properties as suggested by others as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have few options to make flex children not grow. including `flex-grow: 0`

But as a rule of thumb, you should limit your images tags to `max-width: 100%`
that way they will not overflow their container

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper>div {
  width: 50%;
}

.wrapper>div:first-child {
  background: red;
}

.wrapper>div:last-child {
  background: blue;
}

.wrapper>div img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/500x100" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x30" alt=""></div>
</div>
```